# Plot after filtering by categorical variable (error filter(), attempt to apply non-function)

Tags: r, plot, shiny

Roman history fan here. So I have created a small dataframe with the section of the legions `legions` (`fifth` and `tirteenth`), and their `morale` (`high`, `medium`, `low`).

I want visualize the differences on morale by legion. For this I will create a barplot for the legion, filtering by morale.

So in the X axis I will have `fifth` and `tirteenth`, and the concentration filtered by our morale selection.

This is what I have. (Please notice this is a toy example, in reality there are many variables for x, y and factor variable, no romans unfortunately)

```
# Shiny
library(shiny)
library(shinyWidgets)

# Data
library(readxl)
library(dplyr)

# Plots
library(ggplot2)



Legion <- c("Fifth", "Fifth", "Fifth","Fifth","Fifth","Fifth", "Fifth", "Fifth","Fifth","Fifth","Tirteenth","Tirteenth", "Tirteenth", "Tirteenth","Tirteenth", "Tirteenth","Tirteenth", "Tirteenth", "Tirteenth","Tirteenth")
Morale <- c("High", "High", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low", "High", "High", "High", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low","High", "Medium", "Low", "High")
romans <- data.frame(Legion, Morale)


not_sel <- "Not Selected"

# main page display in the shiny app where user will input variables and plots will be displayed
main_page <- tabPanel(
  title = "Plotter",
  titlePanel("Plotter"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      title = "Inputs",
      fileInput("xlsx_input", "Select XLSX file to import", accept = c(".xlsx")),
      selectInput("num_var_1", "Variable X axis", choices = c(not_sel)),
      selectInput("num_var_2", "Filter Y axis", choices = c(not_sel)), uiOutput("binning"),
      br(),
      actionButton("run_button", "Run Analysis", icon = icon("play"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel(
          title = "Plot",
          plotOutput("plot_1")
        )
      )
    )
  )
)



# Function for printing the plots with two different options
# When there is not a selection of the biomarker (we will take into account var_1 and var_2)
# And when there is a selection of the biomarker (we will take into account the three of them)
draw_barplot <- function(data_input, num_var_1, num_var_2, biomarker){
  print(num_var_1)
  
  if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & biomarker == not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]])) +
      geom_bar() + 
      theme_bw()
  }
  
  else if(num_var_1 != not_sel & num_var_2 != not_sel & biomarker != not_sel){
    ggplot(data = data_input, aes(x = .data[[num_var_1]])) +
      geom_bar() + 
      theme_bw()
  }
}


ui <- navbarPage(
  main_page
)


server <- function(input, output){
  
  # Dynamic selection of the data. We allow the user to input the data that they want 
  data_input <- reactive({
    #req(input$xlsx_input)
    #inFile <- input$xlsx_input
    #read_excel(inFile$datapath, 1)
    romans
  })
  
  # We update the choices available for each of the variables
  observeEvent(data_input(),{
    choices <- c(not_sel, names(data_input()))
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_1", choices = choices)
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "num_var_2", choices = choices)
  })
  
  
  # We select the binning level that we want for the plot of the Y axis
  output$binning <- renderUI({
    req(input$num_var_2, data_input())
    a <- unique(data_input()[[input$num_var_2]])
    pickerInput(inputId = 'selected_bins',
                label = 'Select binning for plot',
                choices = c(a[1:length(a)]), selected=a[1], multiple = TRUE,
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)) #options = list(`style` = "btn-warning"))
  })
  
  
   
  num_var_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_1)
  num_var_2 <- eventReactive(input$run_button, input$num_var_2)
  

  ##### BoxPlot ----------------------------------------------------------------
  
  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(input$selected_bins, data_input())
    df <- data_input() %>% dplyr::filter(num_var_1() == input$selected_bins())
    draw_barplot(df, num_var_1())
  })
  
  output$plot_1 <- renderPlot(plot_1())
  
}

# Connection for the shinyApp
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, I'm getting the next error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6C40.png)

This is obviously in the eventReactive of the plot.

Comment: Thank you @YBS, but the error persists. `Problem with filter()input ..1.
[34mi[39m Input ..1 is num_var_1() %in% input$selected_bins().
[31mx[39m attempt to apply non-function`

Comment: That error is due to `input$selected_bins()`.  Please change it to `input$selected_bins`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works for me.

```
  plot_1 <- eventReactive(input$run_button,{
    req(input$selected_bins, data_input(),input$num_var_2)
    df <- data_input() %>% dplyr::filter(.data[[input$num_var_2]] %in% input$selected_bins ) 
    draw_barplot(df, num_var_1(), num_var_2(), biomarker = "selected")
  })
```